# Issue while creating VS2015 solution file with TFS control section by hand

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, projects-and-solutions, premake

We are migrating from plain Visual Studio 2015 solution/projects system to the use of *premake5* that creates `.vcxproj` and `.sln` files itself at each call. This will result in the fact that the `.sln/.vcxproj` files will no longer be source controlled. Since our code is on TFS, I needed to restore the binds by adding some lines to these files. In the `.vcxproj` files, I added the famous `<Scc...>SAK</Scc...>` entries. This added access to TFS contextual menu to each file in the Solution Explorer. So far so good. But all files appear checked out (small red check mark beside) while it shoud be a small blue padlock.

I then tried to add a `GlobalSection` to my solution file, getting inspired by the former solution file we had:

```
GlobalSection<TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = n
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58...184C}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = http://myserver

    SccProjectUniqueName0 = Project0\Project0.vcxproj
    SccProjectName0 = Project0
    SccLocalPath0 = Project0

    ....
EndGlobalSection
```

But when I load the solution in VS2015, I get a message indicating that there are some problems loading some projects... And I found in menu **File/Source Control/Advanced/Change Source Control** that my solution file is not bound.

```
Solution:MySolution.sln    <No Server>    <No Server>    [ ]    Not Controlled
```

Actually, **this is correct** because we do not want to put the solution file on TFS. It will be a volatile file regenerated on each call to *premake5*. Also note that TFS actions run properly...

**My question**: how should I modify my solution file to get rid of this anoying message and to recover the "correct" icons in the Solution Explorer? Something to change in the `.sln` file? Something to change in then `.vcxproj` files? Something else?

Thanks in advance if you can help me!

Comment: Do you mean you want to exclude the solution file (*.sln) from TFS?

Comment: Yes, it's what I want to do. Actually, .vcxproj will also be excluded but the problem seems to be in the .sln exclusion?

Answer (score -1):

You can configure which kinds of files are ignored by placing text file called **.tfignore** in the folder where you want rules to apply.

.tfignore file example:

```
######################################
# Ignore .cpp files in the ProjA sub-folder and all its subfolders
ProjA\*.cpp
#
# Ignore .txt files in this folder
\*.txt
#
# Ignore .xml files in this folder and all its sub-folders
*.xml
#
# Ignore all files in the Temp sub-folder
\Temp
#
# Do not ignore .dll files in this folder nor in any of its sub-folders
!*.dll
```

More information you can refer to the article below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-files-server?view=vsts#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control

---

Update a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I want to do, if you read carrefully my question. `.tfignore` is simply used to prevent TFS system to see a file. My goal is to provide correct entries to VS, telling it that source (.cpp/.h/...) are versioned while .vcxproj and .sln are not.

Comment: The files specified in `.tfignore` are ignored by version control. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: Yes and no. I don't want to have .vcxproj neither .sln on TFS but my concern is about the appearance in VS. If you read my question, you will see that the source files (that are under source control) appear all checked out (modified) with a red check mark while they are not and they should appear with a blue padlock beside them. It is a "look and feel" issue rather than a functionality issue I should say...

Comment: If you unbind the solution file, there should be no icon in front of it. Don't you get this behavior?

Comment: Yep. But the problem is for the icon in front of the source (.cpp,.h,...) files

Comment: From my original post: "My question: how should I modify my solution file to get rid of this anoying message and to recover the "correct" icons in the Solution Explorer? Something to change in the .sln file? Something to change in then .vcxproj files? Something else?"